# python list of dictionaries, how to print the product_id, which "discontinued" equal to '1'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a list of dic, how to print the product_id, which "discontinued" equal to '1'?

```py
products = [
    {
        "discontinued": 0,
        "product_id": 101,
    },
    {
          "discontinued": 0,
        "product_id": 102,
    },
    {
         "discontinued": 1,
        "product_id": 103,
    },
    {
         "discontinued": 1,
        "product_id": 104,
    }
]
```

Comment: did you try anything so far? can you please share?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This is a very low-effort question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a simple list comprehension to get the `product_id` values of only the dicts that have a `discontinued` value of 1:

```py
result = [d['product_id'] for d in products if d['discontinued'] == 1]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[103, 104]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and update. That makes so much more sense now.